# tinymce wildcard usage in class names

Tags: tinymce

```
tinymce.activeEditor.formatter.register('div_class', {block : 'div', classes : '%value'});
tinymce.activeEditor.formatter.remove('div_class',{value : 'alert*'});
```

I am trying to remove all "alert*" classes. Like alert-error, alert-info etc. Seems wildcard in class names is not working.. Any suggestion for this?